# Android application setting connection type

Tags: android, connection, gprs

I'm writing an application for android. My problem is that I want it to force the connection in GPRS and not use wi fi. I have a solution like below, but this causes the crash of the application at start.

```
ConnectivityManager CM = 
    (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
CM.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

I also added the below setting lines into manifest file.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
```

Does anyone know the problem, or an answer to set connection type?

Comment: I would utilize `LogCat`, you would use the `Log` class to leave debug statements inside of your code where you think the problem may lie, and inside of the `LogCat` window you can see a trace of whats causes the crash. Do that, run the application and if it crashes, look inside the console window what caused the crash and post it back here.

Comment: The problem for emulator was about write_secure_settings permission and i have added it to manifest. Now it says the application throws securityException. I have found that to change secure settings, the sign of the application must have been same as the phone itself, but i am not sure about this info. So I guess it may really be  impossible to do it in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I want it to force
>   the connection in GPRS and not use wi
>   fi.

That is not possible in Android today, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to check to see if the Wi-Fi is on, and in Android 2.0 and above you are able to enable or disable the Wi-Fi programmatically.  In Android 1.x, the best you can do is tell the user that they must disable it and point them to the Settings page.

```
/**
 * Checks if Wi-Fi is on. 
 * 
 * @return true, if Wi-fi is on.
 */
public static boolean isWiFiOn()
{
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) MyAccountApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (wifi == null)
        return false;

    List<WifiConfiguration> config = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();

    if (config != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < config.size(); i++)
        {
            if (config.get(i).status == WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}

public static void setWiFi(Context context, boolean enabled)
{
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (wifi != null)
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
}
```